# Allocate variable memory for inner struct in struct

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I have these two structs:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char r, g, b; // color components
    char *code; // color code (char combination)
} Color;


typedef struct {
    unsigned int width; // in pixels
    unsigned int height; // in pixels
    unsigned char cpp; // chars per pixel
    unsigned int nof_colors; // number of colors
    Color *colors; // reference to Color struct table
    unsigned int *data[]; // holds `width` x `height` entries for `colors` codes
} XPM;
```

I then have a function that initializes a given `XMP` struct:

```
void initXPM(XPM *image, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, 
             unsigned char cpp, unsigned int nof_colors) {
    image.colors = [allocate memory for `nof_colors` Colors, 
                    with each color having the length of `code` exactly `cpp`]
}
```

How can I allocate memory for the above struct member?

Comment: Allocate memory like with anything in C, use `malloc` and `free` respectively.  Doesn't matter if its a member of a struct or not.

Comment: `image` is pointer, so `image->colors`, and them use `malloc`

Comment: `chars per pixel` is well known as `bytes per pixel`

Comment: @TonyTheLion, I know, but I have no idea on how to allocate memory for an inner struct member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
image->colors = malloc(image->nof_colors * sizeof *image->colors);
for (..) {
    images->colors[i].code = malloc(..);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof *image->colors` doesn't depend on how large the `Color` struct is (and which you defined after)?

Comment: @AndreiHorak It's a well-known idiom. `sizeof` only cares about the type of `image->colors`, it doesn't dereference it or anything.

Comment: And since the size of `image->colors`'s type can change based on its `code` length, does it allocate the correct amount of memory to `image->colors` even though at that point the size of the `Color` struct is not known?

Comment: @AndreiHorak In your code the size of `Color` is known: **its size does not depend on what you assign to `code`**.

Comment: To complete @cnicutar comment: the size of `Color` is 3 chars + a **pointer** : it does not matter how long is the pointed data, it is still an address that you keep in your allocated structure.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying and for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Using malloc you can allocate the memory to colors

```
image->colors=(Color *)malloc(image->nof_colors * sizeof(Color);
```